# How do you deauthorize using Apple's Authorization Services?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authorization

After preAuthorizing using `AuthorizationCopyRights(...)` how do I unauthorize it using Apple's Authorization Services?

EDIT: Alright, I feel rather unintelligent now. I used to think that I shouldn't free the authorization reference and keep it for future use, but apparently I should make a new one `AuthorizationCreate(...)` every time I want the user to enter credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AuthorizationFree(authRef, kAuthorizationFlagDestroyRights)

as documented in the Authorization.h header

Comment: Thanks, you made me go back and look and finally figure out how authorization works in relation to prompts and everything.